# Extend Add-Ins menu in Word 2010 Ribbon with AutoText/QuickParts

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have *AutoText* / *QuickParts* since Word 2003. For Word 2010 I moved the corresponding *dot** files into the standard startup folder to get them loaded with any Word document.

[image: 1]

These are correctly loaded.

[image: 2]

In the *Add-Ins* menu in the ribbon the correct drop down menus appear.

[image: 3]

But if I add new entries in Word 2010 like *Test* they won't appear in the drop down list.

[image: 4]

E.g. no entry like *Test* appears under *am*.

[image: 5]

All strings with sensitive information in the screenshots have been shortened.

**Question:** What is the correct way in Word 2010 for changing the *Add-Ins* menu?